# How to setup up PAM to unlock gnome-keyring

Tags: pam, display-manager, gnome-keyring

I am trying to use Ubuntu with effectively using [ly display manager](https://github.com/fairyglade/ly), however it does not seem to setup the PAM settings with Debian, I so I need to do this manually. My research shows that this is normally one of the tasks of the display manager.

The problem is the `gnome-keyring` is not unlocked after I log in, I have to enter in my password a second time.

Googling lead me to https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeKeyring/Pam:

> In /etc/pam.d/gdm, add lines like this at the end of the 'auth', 'session' blocks. The 'session' line below should come towards the end of the other 'session' lines. This allows other modules like the pam systemd module to setup environment variables.

So I changed `/etc/pam.d/ly` from this:

```
#%PAM-1.0

auth       include      login
account    include      login
password   include      login
session    include      login
```

to this:

```
#%PAM-1.0

auth       include      login
auth    optional        pam_gnome_keyring.so
account    include      login
password   include      login
session    include      login
session optional        pam_gnome_keyring.so  auto_start
```

`/etc/pam.d/passwd` and `/etc/pam.d/common-password` are unchanged, stock standard Ubuntu 20.04.

`/etc/pam.d/passwd` just has a single line to include `/etc/pam.d/common-password`, which has:

```
password    [success=1 default=ignore]  pam_unix.so obscure sha512
password    requisite           pam_deny.so
password    required            pam_permit.so
password    optional    pam_gnome_keyring.so
```

However is still does not work.

I am not sure what else to try.

Comment: "This makes me think that LightDM or GDM do some extra stuff after you log in to fix all these issue."  It will load and execute dconf settings. That is about it.

Comment: @Nmath, thanks for the suggestions, after googling what the XY problem is, I restated the problem without my assumptions, and focused on one of the issues.

Comment: You mention both Ubuntu and Debian in the first sentence. Can you be more specific which distro and version of Linux you are using?